# Localize functions in the Hardy space $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $f$ belong to the Hardy space $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$, $B\subset \mathbb R^n$ be the unit ball. Does there exist a $\bar f\in \mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact support such that $\bar f=f$ on $B$?

Comment: I guess, the answer is yes (although I am not entirely sure) and you could find it in:  Semmes, Stephen A primer on Hardy spaces, and some remarks on a theorem of Evans and Müller. Comm. Partial Differential Equations 19 (1994), no. 1-2, 277–319.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Thanks. And I think for any $\Omega$ strictly containing $B$, we can let $\bar f$ be supported in $\Omega$: if $f$ vanishes on $\Omega\setminus B$, we can let  $\bar f |_{\Omega\setminus B}$ be any $L^p$ function ($p>1$) such that $\int \bar f=0$. Otherwise, just choose $\theta$ supported in $\Omega$ and smooth such that $\theta=1$ on $B$ and $\int \theta f=0$. Then $\theta f\in \mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$. You may replace your comment as an answer if you like.